# BizTalk 2013R2 - WCF SOAP Adapter without orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Is it possible to expose a SOAP endpoint via BizTalk that calls another SOAP service without using orchestrations but just maps?

The current solution where orchestrations are being used is very slow (orchestration overhead is greater than 1,5 seconds) and performance gets even worse when it comes to high concurrency. I require a solution for low latency.

Answer (score 1):

While not 100% sure for a SOAP endpoint, I have done this for WCF-BasicHttp, but cannot think of a reason why it would not be possible for SOAP. Various properties get promoted to the message context that would allow you to route a message to a send port, like the SOAP action, the receive port name, etc. Configuring a send port to subscribe to the relevant messages should be trivial. The mapping from the inbound-request to the outbound-request can happen on either the receive port or the send port.

In the case of using a solicit-response send port, the response message coming back would automatically be subscribed to by the originating receive port, assuming it is also two-way. Again, the mapping from the inbound-response to the outbound-response can happen on either the send port or the receive port.